# Redirecting old site links to new site

Tags: redirect, wp-redirect

I'm hoping one of you WP gurus can help me out here...

I have a website. Let's call it Jack.com

I'm re-branding Jack as a girl, so I've made another website website - Jill.com

I want all existing links that are spread out over the net to be redirected to the equivalent, sister page
eg. Jack.com/article_12  needs to redirect to Jill.com/article12

Also, If the user types in or clicks on "Jack.com/article_12" but they arrive at Jill.com it's going to leave them a bit confused.
So I'd like to intercept the forwarding with a nice visual page that says "Thanks for visiting, Jack is now a girl called Jill, you are being forwarded to Jill.com/article12" and then redirect the user onto their destination after 5 seconds or so on that intermediate page.

I'm an experienced developer, but WordPress is a total alien to me and I've never had to do this kind of thing before...
Can one of you clever people out there explain how I'd go about doing that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this needs any Wordpress at all. I would set up a single `.php` script setting the headers as such:

```
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"); 
    header('Refresh: 5; URL=http://jill.com/name_of_the_article');
```

And then whatever content you wish. Then I would set up a redirect to the said `.php` script. You would have to fetch the particular name of the article which brought the user there, and you can do that with simple PHP or using Wordpress functions if you so wish (depending how complicated is your redirection, you probably don't need that at all). Also, if you use a different **slug standard** in your new site (as you seem to suggest by removing the underscore), as long as the change is pretty simple, this is going to be quite easy.

If you have problems doing that, we can look into this problem.

**EDIT**

**SOLUTION 1: The simple solution**
This is the simplest solution, using `.htaccess`, but you don't get any timer. Create an `.htaccess` file in the root of your former domain with the following rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.jack.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.jill.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**SOLUTION 2: The more convoluted solution**
Make a php script like so:

```
<?php
    $article = $_GET['article']
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"); 
    header("Refresh: 5; URL=http://jill.com/$article");
?>

<!-- Your HTML goes here, display the timer and whatever you wish -->
```

Then add the following code to your `functions.php` files in Wordpress current theme (or use it as a plugin).

```
function redirect_to_new_site() {

    $article = basename( get_permalink() );
    wp_redirect( "http://jack.com/link-to-your-php-script.php?article=$article", 301);

};

    add_action('wp_head', 'redirect_to_new_site');
```

I have tested this solution and it works.

Comment: Hi Sunyatasattva, Thanks for your post, it sounds encouraging !

I should have pointed out that I'm an experienced developer in vb.net & c# but not php at all.

Are you saying that I need to create a new .php file (and include the header tags you suggest above) and place it in the root of Jack.com?

With .htaccess - would I use this line ?  `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.jill.com/ [R=301]`

That may be wrong because you also said : You would have to fetch the particular name of the article which brought the user there, and you can do that with simple PHP 
What would that php look like ?

Comment: (Removing the underscore from the URL in the example was an accident, the article titles will stay the same)

Comment: I have written a few solutions from you, check them out.

Comment: Sunyatasattva - I'm very sorry about my sporadic replies - I WILL be trying your solutions as soon as my boss gives me some time ! 
In the meantime - please know that I very much appreciate your help here :)