# Editing links to new Site url when user Creates a New Site

Tags: multisite, links

I have a template site set to be duplicated when a user creates a new site on my network.

When a new user creates a new site on my multi-site network I need to have several links incorporate the name of this new users site.

For example, the link in my template site is: 
http://www.yciw.net/template1/quizzes/workflow-quiz/

If a new user creates a site called: oceans

I need the link to automatically update to:
http://www.yciw.net/oceans/quizzes/workflow-quiz/
when the site is created.

Is this even possible?  I've done quite a bit of research. I've seen this post:
[Redirecting old site links to new site](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/85769/redirecting-old-site-links-to-new-site)

but I'm not certain the question is the same.

Comment: I can't really tell what you are doing. What is the code for your "template site", the page with the link on it? How does that work? How does everything fit together?

Comment: The code for the template site is an entire wordpress site. I'm using a plugin called New Blog Template that replicates this template when a user creates a new site. All pages, post etc get copied over. I have several places where links on the template site are pointing to custom posts. For example:  http://www.yciw.net/template1/quizzes/workflow-quiz/

Comment: When the new site is created I need this link to be updated to:   http://www.yciw.net/NAME OF NEW SITE/quizzes/workflow-quiz/